Unable to delete an item in aws dynamodb
Unable to delete an item in aws dynamodb using aws-cli:
Table data in json format:
{
  "primaryKeyAttributeName": {
    "S": "2024-06-17"
  },
 "sortKeyCreatedOn": {
    "S": "2024-06-17Txx:xx:xx.xxx"
  },
  "AttributeName2": {
    "S": "CLOSED"
  },
  "AttributeName3": {
    "L": []
  },
  "lastUpdated": {
    "S": "xxxxxxx"
  },
  "lastUpdatedBy": {
    "S": "xxxx"
  }
}

As per this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/delete-item.html, tried "Example 1" as below
Command which i used for deleting an item:
aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name table-name --key file://C:/dao/key.json --return-values ALL_OLD --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL --return-item-collection-metrics SIZE `  

File contents of C:/dao/key.json:
{
    "primaryKeyAttributeName": {"S": "2024-06-17"},
    "AttributeName2": {"S": "CLOSED"}
}

Am expecting to delete, but receiving this error: 
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema

if i use this command its working and able to display the item: 
aws dynamodb query --table-name tableName --key-condition-expression "primaryKeyAttributeName = :v1" --expression-attribute-values
file://C:/dao/expression-attributes.json --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL

File contents of C:/dao/expression-attributes.json:
{
    ":v1": {"S": "2024-06-17"}
}

if i use this command its not working and receiving the same exception:
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name tableName --key file://C:/dao/key.json --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL

File contents of C:/dao/key.json:
{
    "primaryKeyAttributeName": {"S": "2024-06-17"}
}


Can you share the collection schema definition - the partition and sort keys?

What is your sort key?

Does this answer your question? What is the recommended way to delete a large number of items from DynamoDB?

You have to use the full Primary Key (PK + SK) to delete an item in DDB

If your table has both a primary key and a sort key, then you need to provide both in the --key parameter.  So your C:/dao/key.json JSON file needs to look like this:
{
    "primaryKeyAttributeName": {"S": "2024-06-17"},
    "sortKeyCreatedOn": {"S": "2024-06-17Txx:xx:xx.xxx"}
}

